# selecting by counting fiel

Tags: mysql, sql, firebird

let us suppose we have a query with subquery:

```
SELECT     
    K.NAME,      
     (  SELECT 
         COUNT(*)      
       FROM          
       "001INSIDE_PROCEDURE"     
       ('PARAM1','PARAM2', K.ID, 1) S     ) AS MY_NUMBER,             
FROM
 "001CLIENTS" K   WHERE           
 (K.ACTIVE = 1)  ORDER BY                                
K.NAME
```

It works fine and i've got the column MY_NUMBER.
I'd like to have posibility
WHERE (K.ACTIVE = 1) AND MY_NUMBER = 10
Another words: is there a chance to select by counting columns in a query?

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add another where clause as show below.

```
      SELECT     
        K.NAME,      
         (  SELECT 
             COUNT(*)      
           FROM          
           "001INSIDE_PROCEDURE"     
           ('PARAM1','PARAM2', K.ID, 1) S     ) AS MY_NUMBER             
    FROM
     "001CLIENTS" K
   WHERE           
     (K.ACTIVE = 1) 
    and (  SELECT 
             COUNT(*)      
           FROM          
           "001INSIDE_PROCEDURE"     
           ('PARAM1','PARAM2', K.ID, 1) S) =  10 
  ORDER BY                                
    K.NAME
```

Comment: Sorry, but Firebird reports "Column MY_NUMBER unknown"

Comment: Can you try with new edit? I missed the part the column alias would not be accessible in where clause.

Comment: Yes, it works now, thx for solution. By the way - as i see this is rather ineffective. FB counts twice the same. In my real database the query "without" your solution took about 0.26s and with "patch" it took 1.30s. But anyway it is the way out - thx once again

Comment: I'm glad that solution worked for you. Please accept the answer